# API : How to put useragent into url GET?

Tags: php, api, get, ip, user-agent

In php I would like to use API like this : `website.com/api.php?ip=$ip&ua=$useragent`.

However, with the useragent, variable $response return nothing (it displays nothing as if it was null).

I had tried with only IP address alone and it works fine.

My code :

```
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = 'https://website.com/api.php?ip='.$ip.'&page='.$useragent;
$response = file_get_contents($query);
echo $response;
?>
```

I think it's because of the characters in useragent, do you have any idea how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `urlencode()` function to encode special characters.

And `&page=` should be `&ua=`.

```
$query = 'https://website.com/api.php?ip='.$ip.'&ua='.urlencode($useragent);
```